cdn.office.net error when opening link to SharePoint from ASP.NET Core 8 MVC controller
I have this line of code in an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC view that runs our intranet:
<a href="https://mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com">SharePoint Link</a>

But when I click the link, I get an error from deep within a javascript file called
 cdn.office.net script/shellux/suiteux.shell....

Can anyone tell me what's going on so I can get it working again?
The error is

Message=
Source=
StackTrace:
at t [as constructor] (https://res->1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:29:8>969)
at new t (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:29:19920)
at t.createRefreshRequiredError (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:29:23222)
at t. (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:74:24113)
at https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:24:1785
at Object.next (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:24:1890)
at https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:24:827
at new Promise ()
at C (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:24:572)
at t.acquireCachedToken (https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js:74:23297)


Hi mjh737, please try to access the url https://res-1.cdn.office.net/shellux/suiteux.shell.msaltokenfactoryiframe.f8596e6e29fad0034808.js, I am wondering if it is network-related issue.

Thanks Jason. I was able to access the url directly and see the minified js file.

The good news is that this bug seems to have fixed itself this morning just as quickly as it appeared yesterday.  I'm still getting quite a few errors when I click on the links when I run the web app on my development PC but in production it seems to be working fine now.
